# module http has no exported member 'IncomingHttpHeader'

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I am getting the error 'module http has no exported member 'IncomingHttpHeader' when I run command mnv clean install

Answer (score 0):

Your angular is checking the typings for that package, let's try

```bash
npm install --save-dev @types/express-serve-static-core
```

Comment: still getting the same issue

Comment: i cant see keyword 'IncomingHttpHeader' i my application